# Delete multiple object properties?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I create an object with multiple properties -

```
var objOpts = {
  option1: 'Option1',
  option2: 'Option2',
  option2: 'Option3'
};
```

I then add some more properties later on -

```
objOpts.option4 = 'Option4'
objOpts.option5 = 'Option5'
```

I'm then done with the two latter created properties ('Option4' & 'Option5') and I want to clear/delete both.

Currently I'd do it like so -

```
delete objOpts.option4
delete objOpts.option5
```

Is there another way to go about doing this? Imagine I'd added 5 more properties and needed to clear/delete them all that'd be five lines of almost identical 'delete' code

Comment: `var extraOpts = ['option4','option5','option6','option7','option8']; for(index in extraOpts){ delete objOpts[extraOpts[index]]; }`

Comment: Even better...
`var extraOpts = {};
    extraOpts.options = ['option4','option5','option6','option7','option8'];
    delete extraOpts.options;
    console.log(extraOpts.options);`

Comment: there is a small bug in the first answer: 'let' is missing in for loop. It should be: var extraOpts = ['option4','option5','option6','option7','option8']; for(let index in extraOpts){ delete objOpts[extraOpts[index]]; }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure you are trying to add custom properties to an object.

A simpler way I would suggest is by creating a sub property:

```
objOpts.custom.option4 = 'Option4'
objOpts.custom.option5 = 'Option5'
```

this way you could `delete objOpts.custom` and get done with it. Note that after this step you would have to recreate `objOpts.custom = {}`.

Moreover this way would also feel closer to OOP, since your public properties would easily be distinguishable from private ones.

If you are beginning with deleting objects in JavaScript, I'd like to point to to an excellently written article on the topic: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

You could play around with the meta properties which allow you to protect properties from being deleted etc. (to create an even better coding flow for your case)

*EDIT:*

I'd like to add that instead of deleting and recreating the property, you could simply say `objOpts.custom = {}` which would release the `option4` and `option5` from memory (eventually, via Garbage Collection).

Answer (score 104):

ES6 provides an elegant solution to this: **Rest in Object Destructuring**:

```
let { a, b, ...rest } = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40 };
console.log(rest); // { c: 30, d: 40 }
```

Note that this doesn't mutate the original object, but some folks might still find this useful.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: very neat answer. a little downside is that eslist warns that a & b are assigned but never used

Comment: @AharonOhayon https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings could be used to fix that

Comment: If you declare the deconstructed obj as a `const` won't that remove the elist warning?

Comment: Projects with [ESlint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) - might complain on unused variables, so you might want to disable the rule before for that specific line

Comment: Some linting rules will allow you to denote an unused variable with an underscore like: `_var` while still allowing you to declare it like so: `const { _a, _b, ...rest }`. Otherwise you can add this to your `eslintrc`: `"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "^_", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]` to ignore unused variables or arguments that start with an underscore. I really like the "neat" answer, but as with most neat code it may not be easily understood. You could always wrap it in a named function for better readability though.

Answer (score 49):

There is one simple fix using the library lodash.

The `_.omit` function takes your object and an array of keys that you want to remove and returns a new object with all the properties of the original object except those mentioned in the array.

This is a neat way of removing keys as using this you get a new object and the original object remains untouched. This avoids the problem of mutation where if we removed the keys in the original object all the other parts of code using that object might have a tendency to break or introduce bugs in the code.

Example

```
var obj = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
var result = _.omit(obj, ['x','y']);
console.log(result);

//Output
result = {z:3};
```

Link for the documentation of the same [Click Here](https://lodash.com/docs)

Answer (score 11):

One way is to create a separate function which takes your object and properties as argument.

**[Js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x2rCB/2/)**

Code also below:

```
var objOpts = {
  option1: 'Option1',
  option2: 'Option2',
  option3: 'Option3',
  option4: 'Option4'
};

/** 
 * Method for removing object properties
 *
 */
var removeObjectProperties = function(obj, props) {

    for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
            delete obj[props[i]];
        }
    }

};

// remove
removeObjectProperties(objOpts, ["option1", "option2"]);

// objOpts - after
console.log(objOpts);
```

Comment: The check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])` is not needed, because `delete` does not require the property to exist.

Comment: @mauno-vähä Objects does not have LENGTH prop, I think

Answer (score 8):

A more modern method than Mauno Vänä:

```
function deleteProps (obj, prop) {
    for (const p of prop) {
       delete obj[p];
    }    
}
```

Example:

```
// Create sample object
const myObject = {
    a: 'Foo',
    b: 'Baa',
    c: 'Baz'
};

// Prints: {a: "Foo", b: "Baa", c: "Baz"}
console.log(myObject);

// Delete props
deleteProps(myObject, ['a', 'b']);

// Prints: {c: "Baz"}
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: The check for `(p in obj)` is not needed, because `delete` does not require the property to exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":3,"key4":4};

if (!('multidelete' in Object.prototype)) {
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'multidelete', {
    value: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            delete this[arguments[i]];
        }
    }
});
}

obj.multidelete("key1","key3");
```

> You can use it like this to delete multiple keys in object

Answer (score 0):

One aditionnal otpion would be to use `Object.assign` to set the properties to either `null` or `undefined` depending on your use case. This does not delete the properties but clears them. So you would do either of these :

```
// Modify the object directly
Object.assign(objOpts, {option4: null, option5: null});
```

OR

```
// Create a copy of the object with the properties cleared 
const newObject = Object.assign({}, objOpts, {option4: null, option5: null});
```

You could also use an array to list the properties to clear with `Array.reduce()` to create the last param of `Object.assign()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.keys(object).forEach((prop) => delete object[prop]);
```

Comment: How does this differ from `delete object` ?

Comment: You cannot call `delete` on an object.
`delete` can be used to delete the property of an object, not the object itself.

Comment: How does this allow one to delete specific properties instead of all properties?

Comment: This seems to be a solution for how to delete all of an object's properties, leaving you with `object === {}`. This in no ways answers the OP's question.